# How to tell what library a custom tag is coming from?

Tags: html, vue.js, tags

This is a bit of a weird question, so please bare with me.

So I've joined a new project at work and it's pretty old (Vue2, no ts support, etc.). It also utilizes a couple UI libraries, amongst other dependencies.

As I am combing through, I've found a few tags labeled `<Sider>` and I cannot find where they are coming from. Neither of the UI Libraries seem to utilize it and I cannot just cmd click to see where it's coming from. It's also not a custom component or anything in the app.

Is there anyway to tell where these sorts of tags would be coming from?

This is for work so I can't share the app itself, but here's a quick image of what one of those tags looks like:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is working and the components (Sider and side-menu) are not registered in the component it self, they might be [registered globally (see vue2 docs)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration). Global registration typically gets done in your `main.js` file.

This could also be the reason that you cannot find the component in your project, because it may have another file name. In your main.js might be something like:

```
import TotallyDifferentName from '@/components/TotallyDifferentName.vue'

Vue.component('Sider', TotallyDifferentName) // Now you can use  component in templates as Sider
```

Hope this helps.